# Outlook contacts using Python client

Tags: python, outlook

I want to write a script which permits a user to modify his Contacts, can you help me ?

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You can use Python-COM bindings to use Outlook's COM object and achieve what you want.

[Here](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html)'s a nice tutorial on how to use Python with COM.